# create database in mongodb using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have created a database in mongodb using asp.net mvc but when i look to my database  the insertion is failed .I have tested before in a console application and it works correctly but now I don't find the problem when i use mvc!can you help me please 
this is my code

---

```
  //IDeviseRepository

namespace WebApplication6
  {
  public interface IDeviseRepository
     {
    Devise Add(Devise devise);
    void MongoGoNow();
     }
  }
```

---

```
 //DeviseRepository 

 namespace WebApplication6
  {
      public class DeviseRepository : IDeviseRepository
     {
      public IMongoDatabase db;
      public DeviseRepository()
       {
        MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
        settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
        this.db = client.GetDatabase("bigdata");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Devise>("Devise");

       }


    public IMongoCollection<Devise> Devise
    {
        get
        { return db.GetCollection<Devise>("Devise"); }
    }

    public Devise Add(Devise devise)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Devise>("Devise");
        collection.InsertOne(devise);
        return devise;
    }

    public void MongoGoNow()
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Devise>("devise");
        var result = TestFind(collection);
        result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task TestFind(IMongoCollection<Devise> MyCollection)
    {
        var filter = new BsonDocument();
        var count = 0;
        using (var cursor = await MyCollection.FindAsync(filter))
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var batch = cursor.Current;
                foreach (var document in batch)
                {

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

    }



    public void insertdata()
      {
        var devise = new Devise();
        devise.parité = "euro/dollar";
        Devise.InsertOne(devise);
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the old Mongo Driver. I would recommend first, upgrading to 2.0: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

Comment: Also, what happens if you wrap your insert in a try/catch block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a database in mongodb with asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251180/how-to-create-a-database-in-mongodb-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: OP is keep posting same again with slight change. I'd suggest you to take some course mostly available freely online.

Comment: @PimBrouwers I am using Mongo Driver version 2.2

Comment: @Saleem I had no experience with a mongodb and asp.net mvc .I started to discover this world there is a month ago for my study project.I have to make this project in a month.Can you give me some link for course .thnx

Comment: Try following links. http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/10/02/a-mongodb-tutorial-using-c-and-asp-net-mvc/

https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your insert to:

```
public void insertdata()
{
    try
    {
        var devise = new Devise();
        devise.parité = "euro/dollar";
        Devise.InsertOne(devise);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //put a breakpoint here
    }   
}
```

Comment: I expected that. But was there an exception thrown?

Comment: There is no exception thrown